# Localhost webpage is not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, localhost

I am attempting to create an authorization app with devise and Rails. Previously localhost:3000 was used in ruby rails and i was able to view a ruby acceptance page. However now after creating the app, every localhost i attempt to use now gives the same error message of

```
      This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

i have restarted and it hasn't worked, i disabled firewalls and that didn't work i changed the lan settings so the proxy allow local host and that didn't work! I have no idea why this isn't working. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: have you tried using another port? give following command when starting rails server:                                                                                                rails server -p 8080. if not then try again with the following command: rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000

Comment: Look into the console and into log/development.log for error messages. (And don't forget to switch the firewall on again)

Comment: Are you running your app in a vagrant or other virtualize machine?

Comment: When you start your rails server what is the output you get on terminal ? Can you paste some logs ? Normally your rails app should be accessible on `http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue. Mine was fixed by running the app with webrick instead of puma.

```
rails s webrick
```

Ideally this shouldn't make a difference. I'll do some more digging and will update the response if I find anything.